# C# snippet to create snippets

Tags: c#, code-snippets

Anyone have a snippet (or know where one exists) to create snippets?  I saw one in a video demo for Visual Studio snippets a few weeks ago, but I can't remember where it was.

Comment: Dear god man, don't do it, if it was implemented that sort of recursive overload would cause the universe to explode!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Snippet instructions:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394(VS.80).aspx

Snippet example (snippet.snippet):
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Xml\1033\Snippets\snippet.snippet

Comment: The question is not how to create a snippet, but if you know where a snippet to create a snippet is located.

Comment: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Xml\1033\Snippets\snippet.snippet is a snippet for creating snippets.

Comment: Hey Jim, if you put this comment in the answer itself, I'll vote you up and set it as the correct answer.  Thanks man!

Answer (score 2):

There are VS.NET addins that allow creating snippets from a piece of code you selected in the editor, with a nice designer and stuff. Google for it...

http://www.codeplex.com/SnippetEditor